# Provision List using SharePoint Framework on SP 2016 on-premise

Tags: spfx

I followed this article and I was able to provision List in SharePoint online using below link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package

At time of creating SPFx part, I had selected option of "SharePoint Online Only".

Now, I want to do the same for SP 2016 as well as SP Online, so I selected "Which baseline packages do you want to target for your component(s)?". I was not able to find "SharePoint" folder created which I was getting while selecting "SP Online Only" as shown in screenshot below:
[image]

While with SP2016, I get below folder strucutre created:

[image]

Can anyone please help where should I place the xml files ? I manually created the structure but while packaging the project, I get below error. I did not get any build errors though.

> No manifests were found in 'dist*.json'. Ensure a build has completed successfully and that paths.manifestsMatch is correct

Comment: Did you try to create a `sharepoint` folder, put your xml files in it, and reference them in your *package-solution.json* ? The `sharepoint` folder is automatically created when needed, and in a SPFx project, it is only needed when compiling/packaging the project

Comment: I did tried creating it manually and referring in package-solution.json. but doing so throws error specified in Question.

Comment: Would you mind removing any reference to your XML provisioning, then executing `gulp clean`, `gulp build`, `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship`. Then, try to re-incorporate the XML files. Another question is, can you create an application customizer in your solution ? Where is the XML generated ? Another resolution clue would be to look where they have defined `paths.manifestsMatch` (probably in node_modules, but its definition should help you know where to put your XML files)